# Use of percent sign (%) as a CMD parameter is interpreted as a variable

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, wget

I try to run a batch file with the following code:

```
wget.exe "http://example.com/file0%24.html"
```

The problem is, that CMD is interpreting the `%2` as a variable (the second command line parameter) and since it isn't defined, it's empty.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Where is the batch file?

Comment: thats only a line of code from that batch file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a double-percent sign to send a percent literal.

```
wget.exe "http://example.com/file0%%24.html"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape % as %%

> wget.exe "http://example.com/file0%%24.html"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634