# Passing percent sign in a batch parameter CALL

Tags: batch-file, cmd

On Windows 7....

This SO Answer seems to be in error for me:
[Use of Percent Sign as a CMD Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388754/use-of-percent-sign-as-a-cmd-parameter-is-interpreted-as-a-variable?rq=1)

In Called.bat

```
echo 1=%1
```

Caller Bat

```
call called.bat "percent%%sign"
```

Results

percent%%sign = percent

"percent%%sign" = "percent"

percent^%sign = percent

"percent^%sign" = "percent^%sign"

percent%%%%sign= percent

percent%%%sign= percent

"percent%%%%sign" = "percent"

"percent%%%sign" = "percent"

Comment: What is exactly the question? What do you expect? What do you need?

Comment: I want the echo to respond with something like percent%sign.

Answer (score 2):

**caller**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

CALL qq22658604 "percent%sign"
CALL qq22658604 "percent%%sign"
CALL qq22658604 "percent%%%sign"
CALL qq22658604 "percent%%%%sign"
CALL qq22658604 percent%sign
CALL qq22658604 percent%%sign
CALL qq22658604 percent%%%sign
CALL qq22658604 percent%%%%sign

GOTO :EOF
```

**qq22658604**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
ECHO 1=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

**results**

```
1="percentsign"
1="percentsign"
1="percentsign"
1="percent%sign"
1=percentsign
1=percentsign
1=percentsign
1=percent%sign
```

NFF.

Answer (score 0):

When I use a `second.bat` with

```
@echo off
echo %~1
```

There are two cases now.
If you call `second.bat` from a batch file, the `CALL` line in the caller batch needs to be
`call called.bat "percent%%%%sign"`
You could omit the quotes, as long as there are no spaces inside the parameter

If you call the `called.bat` directly from the cmd-prompt you can use
`call called.bat "percent%sign"`

Comment: Four percentage signs with the quotes do not work for me. Did you run it on your machine? Is there some strangeness with ECHO going on?

Comment: @MarkRobbins Yes, I tested it with Win7x64, but this should also work on any other windows system

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one is my bad. The issue is caused by cmd shell software called "Take Command" v13 by JP Software. The echo command is behaving differently. I have no insight on how to get it working correctly at this time.