# Bat file - prompt command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following command

```
explorer "http://10.0.100.5/QvAJAXZfc/AccessPoint.aspx?open=&id=QVS@srv-qlickview%7C.qvw&client=Plugin"
```

I saved this command in bat file but when I run it , it loops. The command is executed so many time .
How to use it properly in batch file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of percent sign (%) as a CMD parameter is interpreted as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388754/use-of-percent-sign-as-a-cmd-parameter-is-interpreted-as-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the % sign with `%%`, so

```
explorer "http://10.0.100.5/QvAJAXZfc/AccessPoint.aspx?open=&id=QVS@srv-qlickview%%7C.qvw&client=Plugin"
```

Comment: Not sure if `^%` works in a batch file; you might use `%%` instead... since the URL is in between `""`, you should not need to escape the `&`...

Comment: Thanks; you should also adapt the text accordingly, not only the code; moreover, I think you should provide both options (`%%` and `^%`) as the question is tagged [tag:batch-file] _and_ [tag:cmd] (resp.)...