# parse arguments from command line interface with special character %

Tags: python, argparse

I am developing an application taking input from the user (*path*) and using it later however some problems when the path had special characters like `%` for example `(C:\path%25 -> C C:\path5)`

Is there any way to stop the parser from applying the skipping characters?

Am using the following code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--path', help='Specifies the input path', nargs="*", dest='path', required=True, type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.path)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of percent sign (%) as a CMD parameter is interpreted as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388754/use-of-percent-sign-as-a-cmd-parameter-is-interpreted-as-a-variable)

Comment: @djstrong I can't actually change the path in the batch file since it is called via GUI and the path from an existing file that might have the % sign in its name

Comment: what is `sys.argv` and `print(args)` in this case?

Comment: Most likely the problem is in how the shell/interpreter splits the input.  You'll see this in `sys.argv`.  `%` in a argument string doesn't mean anything special to `argparse`.  Quoting the path might solve the issue.

Comment: @AhmedBenSoltane I think it is Windows thing and not the parser, so you can't do anything from the application point of view.

Comment: @hpaulj I am sure it is related to the batch scripts which interpret the %2 as the second argument so it just replace it with a void and then passes it to the argparser, I tried both the single and double quotes and nothing seems to be working. Any other ideas how to solve this ?